# Break a record into multiple record for calendar year ranges

Tags: sql-server, view

I have a table that i need to join using ZIP column to another table to create a view

```
--table 1
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZIP](
[ZIP] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[BEG] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[END] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ZIP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ZIP] ASC,
[BEG] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into ZIP select '64112', '01/01/2012', '12/31/2045'
insert into ZIP select '64113', '01/01/2012', '12/31/2045'
insert into ZIP select '64114', '01/01/2012', '12/31/2045'

--table 2
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZIPCODE](
[ZIP] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[STATUS] [varchar](12) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ZIPCODE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ZIP] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY]



insert into ZIP select '64112', 'BMMNNNNNNNNN'
insert into ZIP select '64113', 'BMNNNNNNNNNB'
insert into ZIP select '64114', 'BMPNNNNNNNNP'
```

Table 1 records traverse multiple years so i want to break this down into Calendar year ranges like below and if today's date falls within a certain date range then the END date should be '12/31/2045'

```
'64112', '01/01/2012', '12/31/2012'
'64112', '01/01/2013', '12/31/2013'
'64112', '01/01/2014', '12/31/2014'
'64112', '01/01/2015', '12/31/2045'
```

Table 2 STATUS column 'NNNNNNNNNNNN'

Table 2 STATUS column is set in a way that each position references a CY. First position is 2004, second is 2005, third is 2006, so on ......., twelfth is 2015 in the above string and each position can have one of the 4 values N, B, P or M

The view i want to create needs to pull the records like below

```
'64112', '01/01/2012', '12/31/2012', N
'64112', '01/01/2013', '12/31/2013', N
'64112', '01/01/2014', '12/31/2014', N
'64112', '01/01/2015', '12/31/2045', N
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's got to be one of the ugliest things I've ever seen in a database.

So the only thing I can come up with is to union together a row for each zip/year along with substringing out the status, like so:

```
select
zip,
cast('2012-01-01' as date) as TheYear,
substring(status,10,1) as Status
from
zipcode
UNION
select
zip,
cast('2013-01-01' as date) as TheYear,
substring(status,11,1) as Status
from
zipcode
```

Then you can join your `ZIP` table to that.  Here's an [example in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/703b9/8). I'm sure I didn't get the positions for the years correct, and I sure didn't do all the years, but this should get you going, I think.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew i will use this union to break the ranges